# Link button in DT datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am struggling with this issue of trying to add a link to my data.  I've read a few things and they seem to work but transposing into my app is proving daunting.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here's my code.  I'm trying to create a link that references the Messier Objects and pulls from Wiki.

The app is located at: https://astronomerforfun.shinyapps.io/Observing_List/

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggvis)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

createLink <- function(val) {
  sprintf('<a href="https://www.google.com/#q=%s" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Info</a>',val)
}

# wiki <- function(number){
#   x <- paste0('<a href="https://en.wikipidia.org/wiki/Messier_',number, sep = "")
#   return(x)
# }

source("script.R", local = TRUE)
ui <- navbarPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),"Night Sky",
  tabPanel("OBSERVING LIST", value = "messiertab",

           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               checkboxGroupInput("lists", "Report", choices = c("Messier" = "Messier Objects", 'Herschel 400' = "Herschel 400")),
               h5("Assumptions: Magnifications of Diffuse Objects were reduced by 1."),
               selectInput("season", "Season", c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall")),
               h5("Seasons based on Northern Hemisphere"),
               selectInput("light", "Light Zone", Zone_Table$Zone, NULL),
               h5("Choose Light Zone (Red = Mag 7 and below , Yellow = Mag 9 and below, White = Mag 8 and below, Green = Mag 10 and below")


             ),

             mainPanel(
               # fluidRow(csvDownloadUI("dwnld", "DOWNLOAD"), style = "padding:10px"),
               dataTableOutput("messier")
        )
           )))










# Define server logic required to draw a histogram

    server <- function(input, output, session){


    df <- reactive({
      if(is.null(input$lists)) return(NULL)
      x <- input$lists
      yy <- finaldf%>%
        filter(List == x[1] | List == x[2])
      return(yy)
    })

season <- reactive({
  if(is.null(df())) return(NULL)
  curr_ssn <- switch(input$season,
                     Summer = Summer,
                     Fall = Fall,
                     Spring = Spring,
                     Winter = Winter)

  xxg <- df()$Constellation %in% curr_ssn
  yyyy <- df()[xxg,]
  h <- Zone_Table[Zone_Table$Zone == input$light,]
  j <- yyyy[yyyy$Magnitude <= h$MaxMag,]
  print(j)
  return(j)

})

# lightpollution <- reactive({
#   h <- Zone_Table[Zone_Table$Zone == input$light,]
#   j <- df()[df()$Magnitude >= h$MaxMag,]
#   return(j)
# })



output$messier <- renderDataTable({
  season()$Link <- createLink(season()$Name)
  DT::datatable(season(),
                rownames = FALSE, 
                extensions="Buttons",options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')),

                escape = FALSE)
})


# dwnld <- reactive({
#   tmp2 <- season()
# })
# 
# observe({
#   callModule(csvDownload,"dwnld", dwnld)
#   # print(marginfordwnld())
# })
# 
# 
# }
# Run the application 
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```